# R Shiny list2env

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny application in which the server.R looks like below :

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
   temp<-reactive({
            obj1<-read.csv(.....)
            v1<-c("obj2")
            lst<-lapply(v1,read.csv(....)
            list2env(lst)
           ...
       })
```

I'm creating an object directly in the reactive function called `obj1` and also creating `obj2` using list2env. Both `obj1` and `obj2` are not in the same environment. What is the environment I'm in when I'm inside a reactive function?
Also, I don't want to use `.GlobalEnv` in `list2env` as it would make this object available across all user sessions. How do I make `list2env` create `obj2` in the same environment as `obj1` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `environment()` function will return the current environment. Thus if you use it inside a function, it will return the function's environment. You can then use that with

```
list2env(lst, envir=environment())
```

(Although personally I almost always find it easier to keep data in a list rather than create a bunch of separate variables in the environment.)